# Binding a property in a object list which is in-turn a property of another list from View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a property (text box) which is a part of a list. And that list is a property in another list (class). Now when I write something in that text box , the ancestor one should get updated. I have tried RaisePropertyChanged() but its not working out. Can anyone provide me with right syntax??

Comment: *"I have tried RaisePropertyChanged() but its not working out"* - sounds like a request for debugging help. But where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

When binding lists you should take a look at [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%20INotifyCollectionChanged). RaisePropertyChanged propagates that the list itself (not just one item in it) changed. If bound to a GUI the GUI will check for a change and sees the same old list in place, so it takes no further action.